# MPMoviePlayerController audio doubles after resuming paused video

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

Using MPMoviePlayerController in a view. I'm using custom controls. When I hit pause, fine. When I then hit play, I hear the previous multiple streams of audio. It's like an echo. Anyone run across this?